Good references for the P3/P1dc element
I am struggling to find some good references for the P3/P1dc element (cubic element for velocity and linear piecewise discontinuous for pressure) for the Stokes/Navier-Stokes equations.
Is there a name for this element, like the Taylor-Hood element, the Crouziex-Raviart element, etc.?
I would appreciate it very much if you could point me to some good references with proofs of inf-sup stability and convergence of error norms for this element or its family.

Pretty much everything that has to do with finite element methods for the Stokes and Navier-Stokes equations is discussed at length (really, at much greater length than you probably want) in the more than 1000 pages of the book "Incompressible Flow and the Finite Element Method" by Gresho and Sani. In particular, Section 3.13 with its nearly 200 pages will have all the references you are looking for.
